# CSS Inline Coding

Tags: css, html

I have following code with a div `#letmeout` in it. Due to the outer `<div>` having `position:relative` and `overflow hidden;` set, the `#letmeout` div is not displayed. I need to display `#letmeout` without modifying the outer `<div>`.

```
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;"> 
    <div id="letmeout" width="100%" height="1000px" style=".....">ok</div>
</div>
```

I tried adding an inline style `background:red; position: absolute; z-index: 10000; color:blue; left: 0px; top: 0px; height:10000px; display:marker; overflow:auto; margin:0px;` but `#letmeout` is still not shown. How can I do this without modifying the outer div and only using inline styles on `#letmeout`?

Comment: not really sure what you are trying to achieve here...can you rephrase your question

Comment: do you want letmeout to make the container div grow? Or do you want the container div to stay fixed size and have letmeout flow freely?

Comment: As a potentially useful note to others, `#letmeout` *is* shown if you add some text inside the outer div (at least in Firefox 5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assigning relative positioning to the parent you "locked" the sub (child) into the parent container.

If you really need a screen takeover (as your code suggests) `#letmeout { position:fixed; }` may help. Be warned though, fixed positioning doesn't act like absolute or relative. `fixed` elements take their position based on the viewport.

Check it out: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning

You will also find explanations to your positioning and float options at that URL as well.

Comment: Actually the child container want to take over the screen by having parameters position: absolute; z-index: 10000; width:100%, height:10000px; but position:fixed works for that area only. But it doesn't cover the whole screen though. others blocks are still showing, how can make child container to take over the screen  :)

Comment: Out of votes, but setting `position: fixed` did work in [my jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/bemace/d8n65/).

Comment: If there are other children further down in the document that have position:relative set, they'll still display atop the "take over" div because that's how document flow works. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WuftH/